# How can I figure out ORA-00900 invalid SQL statement in datagrip

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, datagrip

Normally, using `show errors` can solve this problem in SQL*PLUS.

However executing `show errors` in datagrip will show `Nothing to run`, and executing a procedure which has invalid SQL statement only shows error `invalid SQL statement`.

So I can't figure out what's wrong with my procedure.

BTW I'm using macOS so configuring Oracle environment in Windows is a little troublesome.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Perhaps you may try to run "<oracle_home>/rdbms/admin/utlrp.sql" by connecting sqlplus as admin To see invalid statements or objects

Comment: Which version of Oracle database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`show errors` is a SQL*Plus command, not a SQL statement. Even IDEs dedicated to Oracle (e.g. PLSQL Developer) don't recognise it in their SQL Worksheets, so it's not surprising that a generic database IDE hurls. Maybe DataGrip has the option to associate a command line executable for running scripts?

`show errors` is just a wrapper for a query on the data_dictionary. You can execute this for yourself in any SQL environment:

```
 select e.line, e.position, e.text 
 from user_errors e
 where e.name = 'YOUR_PROCEDURE'
 order by e.sequence;
```

The data dictionary view has other attributes you may want to use. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-2237BC4D-F34A-48C5-8181-85426077E65B.htm#REFRN20065).